# How to combine default fields in form on Django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 3 fields in model.py in two of them I put random number

```
def random1():
    #return first random number

def random2():
    #return second random number

class Shakf(models.Model):
    random1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=random1)
    random2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=random2)
```

How do I make a third field which would combine those two? For example:

```
random1 = 3333
random1 = 5555
third_field = "3333 | 5555"
```

There is a important condition: "after reloading admin page they have to change".
If I do like that:

```
third_field = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=random1 + " | " + random2)
```

then I got different random1 numbers and different random2 numbers

if I call function then after reload page I got the same numbers (without changing) .

Comment: What you mean by this, *"after reloading admin page they have to change"*?

Comment: Apart from that, Django admin shows the value from DB, which won't change (unless, you wrote some logic for that) in every refresh